# Capture JPEG image on Android with specified name using adb and activity manager

Tags: android, automation, camera, adb

*Update*
I perfectly understand, that all applications are different, and there is no standard. I'm asking the following question in hope that it will be read by someone possessing knowledge of internals of Samsung camera apps.

I'm developing an automation tool, that should capture images using Android smartphone.

The smartphone is always connected to the PC using USB cable and is controlled by adb.

Up to now I've managed to launch camera application, send it `KEYCODE_CAMERA` event and pull the newest file in the default camera directory (`/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`):

```
adb am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA -n com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera       # launch camera app.
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_CAMERA   # take a picture
adb shell ls -t /sdcard/DCIM/Camera | head -1   # determine name of newly created file
```

I don't like that I cannot turn off auto exposure and other "magic", enabled in Samsung camera apps by default. I also cannot control file name.

I've found another action, `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE`. When I launch intent with it, the camera app doesn't show any additional controls.

When I send `KEYCODE_CAMERA` event, it shows a preview of a captured image and two buttons "Repeat" and "Ok". This preview disappears after I issue `KEYCODE_ENTER` event.

However, I don't see any file with captured image.

Activity manager shows lots of command line switches when run without parameters, that suggest that it gives rich opportunities.

Is it possible to make the camera activity to save file?

I'm using Galaxy Tab S4 with Android 8.1, camera app version is 8.0.11.11

Comment: There are hundreds, if not thousands, of camera apps for Android, both pre-installed and user-installed. If you do not like the behavior of this camera app, install another. Or, write your own using a camera library (CameraX eventually, or something like Fotoapparat or CameraKit-Android today). Your own camera app can then expose its own control surfaces (broadcasts to be triggered by `adb`, a Web service API, etc.).

Comment: I'm thinking in this direction. However, it would be a pity if it appears that solution is just a new command line argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no standard `adb` options that allow you to control arbitrary camera apps to perform arbitrary actions. Similarly, there are no standard `adb` actions to print a file, start a dishwasher, or launch a rocket. All you can do with `adb` and the `am` command is craft an `Intent` — the details of what might be allowed in that `Intent` are up to the recipient of the `Intent`, as with all APIs ever created.

Nobody, other than the developers of the camera app, know what undocumented and unsupported `Intent` options there might be for that app. Saying that it is a "Samsung" camera app merely limits the scope to a few dozen different pre-installed camera apps that Samsung has shipped over the years.

You are certainly welcome to examine the source code to open source camera apps and see if any offer `Intent` options that would allow you to accomplish what you want via `adb`. However, there is no guarantee that those will remain unchanged as that camera app evolves over time.

Comment: I understand that there is no standard. I'm asking in hope that there will be someone with knowledge of internals.

Comment: @wl2776: But "the internals" would be for the camera app, and neither you nor I nor anyone else knows what camera app you are using. All that we know is that you are running it on a Samsung. Based on the *wide* range of Samsung devices that I have used, I would be stunned if they had fewer than a dozen separate camera apps. Even if we knew the exact camera app that you are trying to hack into, it is rather unlikely that anyone is going to know much about it and post about it here on your question.